# Easiest way to draw a full neo4j graph in networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, neo4j, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I have a neo4j graph and I want to draw the entire graph in an ipython notebook with network x. How do I go about doing that?

Something like this?

```
g1 = nx.neo4j_graph
nx.draw(g1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use ipython-cypher to write a Cypher query and then convert the results to a NetworkX graph. Install it with `pip install ipython-cypher`.

```
import networkx as nx
%load_ext cypher
%matplotlib inline

results = %cypher MATCH p = ()-[]-() RETURN p

g = results.get_graph()

nx.draw(g)
```

Drawing your entire graph is expensive if it is large. Consider only drawing the subgraphs you're interested in. You'll also have to tweak the query slightly if you want nodes with degree 0.